# R.layout.activity_signedin shows "cannot resolve symbol"

Tags: java, android

for some reason my contentview is in error due to the R.layout.signedin

```
package com.example.myapplication;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.os.Bundle;


public class signedin extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_signedin);
  }
}
```

Comment: show us the layout please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you should always name the activity in camel case. like, SignedInActivity. 
and also add Activity at the end to denote that it is an activity class. (Just some conventions).
Now coming to the problem, it's just a linting problem. It happens sometimes. don't worry, your app will run just fine. Unless you have deleted the layout file. In that case you need to add a layout file in the res/layout folder named activity_signedin.xml.

Comment: i see, ty for the help! i will definitely use your tips as well.